# How to automate the manual input for command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ansible, serverspec

I have command called serverspec-init
which prompts

```
Select OS type:

  1) UN*X
  2) Windows

Select number:
```

Now I have manually enter value 1 or 2.
But I want to automate this so when i run script it automatically pick the value from variable and give input here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get my WSL installation working, for some reason, but I believe that you're looking for the `$OSTYPE` environment variable.  On my Ubuntu machine, the value is `linux-gnu` and a MINGW shell gives `msys`.

Note that you'll need to make sure that your script is explicitly running BASH.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `expect` module:

```
- name: Select OS
  expect:
    command: /path/to/serverspec-init
    responses:
      Select number: "{{ OS_type_num }}"
```